# Show that $z \mapsto \exp(\overline{z})$ is not complex differentiable at any point in the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

> Show that $z \mapsto \exp(\overline{z})$ is not complex differentiable at any point in the complex plane.

Is it satisfactory to show that $f(z)=e^{\overline{z}}$ does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations to conclude that the map isn't complex differentiable/holomorphic?

If $z \in \Bbb C$ then we can write $z=x+iy$ and thus $$f(z)=e^{x-iy}=e^x\cos(y)-ie^x\sin(y).$$ If I know let $u(x,y)=e^x\cos(y)$ and $v(x,y)=-e^x\sin(y)$, then $$\frac{\partial u}{ \partial x}=e^x\cos(y) \ne \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=-e^x\cos \left(y\right)$$ and $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-e^x\sin \left(y\right) \ne -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=e^x \sin(y)$$

so $f$ doesn't satisfy the C-R equations.

Comment: Yes, it is satisfactory to show that $f$ does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. What are your doubts about it?

Comment: I was wondering if there could exists a holomorphic function that doesn't satisfy the C-R equations, but apparently this is impossible?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Riemann_equations#Complex_differentiability): If $f$ is real-differentiable then it is complex-differentiable *exactly if* the CR equations hold.

Comment: You have brushed some details under the rug. Complex-differentiability at a point $z_0 = x_0 + iy_0$ implies that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied at $(x_0, y_0)$. Setting $u_x(x_0, y_0) = v_y(x_0, y_0)$ and $u_y(x_0, y_0) = -v_x(x_0,y_0)$ yields $\cos y_0 = 0$ and $\sin y_0 = 0$, as your calculations show. This contradicts the fact that $\sin^2y_0 + \cos^2 y_0 = 1$, and thus $f$ is not complex-differentiable anywhere. Your write-up seems to check if certain functions are identical (this is not what you should be doing unless you are required to show that the function is entire).